# Django: loading images from URLs (not static files)

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, web

I'm trying to load a page in Django with data from an API that include image URLs.
I am loading the API data into my modules (example: News module which has a `banner_url` attribute).
In my HTML template, I am loading the banner into an `img` tag:

```
<img src={{ news.banner_url }}>
```

All other attributes (like `title`, `published_date` etc) work but obviously this isn't working, but I haven't been able to find a solution on the internet.
My news module looks like this:

```
class News(models.Model):
        banner_url = models.URLField(null=True) #null is true for the initialization before a URL is fetched.
```

I tried also using many other fields like `CharField` and `ImageField` but to no avail in any way.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if you look at the resulting HTML, what is the src value of the img?

Comment: It is actually fetching the URL correctly but Django does not allow it to show in the page.

Comment: Can you send value of src for the img tag?

Comment: could you check your web console and check 1: is the url in the imr src correct, 2: is there any error when trying to resolve the url?

Comment: I have checked the value of `src` continuously and the link is correct. However, when I open the image link (middle click) it doesn't load immediately but rather after a second refresh. Note that this happens to any link not just one link, and the source is different each time. Note 2: no errors whatsoever observed.